# Can I change Django's sessionid token length?

Tags: python, django

I would like to change the length of Django's sessioid tokens, so instead of 32 characters it would be something insane, like 64 characters. I know that's a lot, but can it be done? Are there reasons to never do something like this?

I know the key length is defined in **django.contrib.sessions.backends** in **class SessionBase**, but I can't seem to find instructions how to override backend functions or replace them.

Ps. I'm new to web development, so I find it difficult to understand some of the documentation. With C++ it was so much easier...

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do this?

Comment: Sure. Short answer is because my "supervisor" or the person who's giving me the tasks wants it done that way. Even if I don't think it is necessary, I really need a good reason not to do it, so it doesn't seem like resistance because of laziness or lack of skill. I don't really have the authority of experience as he works in cyber security and I'm new to web development. I'm doing an API that other programs will use, and I was asked to do it using Django's sessions, even though generally session authentication is used for browsers and AJAX, as I've learned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Subclassing in Django is just the same as in C++; you just need to define a new class that inherits from the base one and overrides the relevant method.

In your case the session key is defined in the `_get_new_session_key` method. You need to inherit from whichever session backend you are already using - eg the db, file or cache backends - and define that method. For example:

```
from django.contrib.sessions.backends.db import SessionStore as OriginalSessionStore

class SessionStore(OriginalSessionStore):
    def _get_new_session_key(self):
        "Returns session key that isn't being used."
        while True:
            session_key = get_random_string(64, VALID_KEY_CHARS)
            if not self.exists(session_key):
                break
        return session_key
```

Now you can use `"path.to.module.with.overridden.class"` in your `SESSION_ENGINE` setting.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Ok, so I have the "SESSION_ENGINE = 'my_api.customsessionstore'" in **settings.py**, and I have the new class in **customsessionstore.py**. I'm just wondering what I need to do now to make it work. Now when a user logs in, a 32-long sessionid is still created. Do I need to call some function myself after login, like request.session.set_session_key() or should it actually replace the overridden class?

Comment: My mistake, looks like Django expects the class to be called SessionStore, so it was still picking up the default one you imported. I've updated the code, try it now.

Comment: Thank you, I got it working now! I marked your answer as accepted. Don't know if it was somewhat in vain for me, as I just noticed that Django's session_key Field is limited to length 40, and Django doesn't support child classes overriding the Fields of parent classes... But at least 40 characters is longer than 32, and I learned something :)